# Asp.net Core Large File Upload in Nginx connection timeout issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linux, nginx, asp.net-core

I've Asp.net core App running in Digital Ocean 10$ Ubuntu Droplet,Having Issue when uploading multiple or large files ,connection disconnected after some time ,don't know what to do here is my proxy settings :

```
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    client_max_body_size 1000m;
    client_body_buffer_size 1000m;
    uwsgi_read_timeout     1000s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_send_timeout 100;
    proxy_read_timeout 100s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 1000s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1000s;
    proxy_buffers 32 4k;
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at your log files?

Comment: Increase your `proxy_send_timeout` and `proxy_read_timeout`.

Comment: thanks for reply poke ,in logs i've error "connection refused while connecting to upstream"

Comment: thanks Ivan Shatsky ,i've changed proxy_send_timeout and proxy_read_timeout ,but it did not help

Comment: Just for reference, had the same issue, increased read/write timeout + body size, in my case file size is not more than 100MB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this on action:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(1024*1024*100)]
public IActionResult Post(){
}
```

or Program.cs for global setting

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 1024*1024*100; //100MB
    });
}
```

or this one from middleware

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = null;
    //TODO: take next steps
});
```